# Xamarin Insights API: dsym upload error Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity

Tags: xamarin

Posting this here because the Xamarin support told me to. I hope someone from xamarin is available to answer me on this.

Our build task to upload the ios symbol files reports this message upon attempting to upload the dsym package:

### “Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity”

Is this a temporary issue?

Recently we added plenty of images to the ios solution to support all resolutions so instead of 22 mb the dsym package is now 52mb. Is that a problem or is it just the backend which is out of storage space currently?

I also had to change the upload implementation to account for the original implementation running into a timeout exception:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/zip"); ;
    this.WriteLogMessage(" Uploading file to Xamarin.Insights API ...");
    var response = client.UploadFile(new Uri($"https://xaapi.xamarin.com/api/dsym?apikey={InsightsApiKey}", UriKind.Absolute), tmpFileName);
    this.WriteLogMessage($"  Response: {Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response)}");
    this.WriteLogMessage(" Done.");
}
```

Turned into

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(tmpFileName, FileMode.Open))
using (var streamContent = new StreamContent(fileStream))
{
    httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(this.UploadTimeoutLimitInSeconds);

    this.WriteLogMessage($" Uploading file to Xamarin.Insights API (Timeout {httpClient.Timeout.TotalSeconds}s) ...");
    string responseText;
    using (MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        var allBytes = await streamContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        form.Add(new ByteArrayContent(allBytes, 0, allBytes.Length), "symbol", Path.GetFileName(tmpFileName));
        var requestUri = new Uri($"https://xaapi.xamarin.com/api/dsym?apikey={InsightsApiKey}", UriKind.Absolute);
        using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(requestUri, form))
        {
            responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                this.WriteLogMessage($"  Error: {response.ReasonPhrase}");
            }
            else
            {
                this.WriteLogMessage($"  Response: {responseText}");
            }
            this.WriteLogMessage(" Done.");

            return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
        }
    }
}
```

Just in case this has to do anything with the code being changed.

Comment: see https://xamarin.statuspage.io, Insights is reporting degraded performance ATM

Comment: @Jason Thanks. didn't know about that page.